# Block Date with Custom Calendar in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I created a custom calendar for block the dates in react native. When I get json response from the Api service. I want to highlight the blocked dates in calendar. Thanks in advance.

```
    <Calendar
    hideArrows={false}
    onDayPress={onDaySelect}
    markedDates={_markedDates}
    minDate={currentDate}
    maxDate={aftertwomonths} />
```

const [_markedDates, set_markedDates] = useState([]);
const onDaySelect = (day) => {

```
const _selectedDay = moment(day.dateString).format(_format); 
let selected = true;
if (_markedDates[_selectedDay]) {
  selected = !_markedDates[_selectedDay].selected;
}
setstatus(true);
const updatedMarkedDates = {
  ..._markedDates,
  ...{ [_selectedDay]: { selected } },
};
set_markedDates(updatedMarkedDates);
}
```

};